# Violate z-index, and force element to front anyway (or fake it)

Tags: css, dom, z-index, css-transforms

I'll preface my question by saying I'm not specifically married to a "z" solution here, but I'm not sure what else would work.

**Task:** Append a masking element (fixed, opacity .5, etc...) over the top of a page, then target a single element within the page and force it to display over the top of that mask. The idea is to highlight particular elements integrated into the page for presentation purposes.

**Restrictions:** The element to force to the top is not defined ahead of time, any element on the page should be a viable target.

Parents of the targeted element will have several possible z-index values, all of which will be lower than the mask's z, and none of which can be changed. Recursively looping through all the parents and setting temporary css styles won't work because it will break a lot of other stuff in the process.

Css-only solution is preferable, although something requiring a little js would be ok.

**Ideas:** The most promising thought I had was to use translateZ (or another 3dTransform type style) to force a single element over the top of all the un-transformed content (including the mask), but so far haven't gotten it to work.

I also considered cloning the targeted element, collecting position and style values from the target and rendering the clone over the top of the mask. This seems a little clumsy (and kinda gross) and I'm not sure how bullet-proof it is.

---

All the other solutions I've read so far involve reordering the dom, correcting the position or z-index styles on the parent(s), or simply adding a missing position style to the target... none of which are applicable solutions here.

Comment: `z-index` and z transform (`translateZ` for example) are unrelated. increasing `z-index` can work though. provide sample code.

Comment: requires Javascript:  clone your element, add it as a child of your masking overlay, then set its position on page to be the same as the original element's position.

Comment: +1 twice. Clone it... or manage temporary z-index-es on parents of the element sent to the top (store their current states - position and z-index - then give them needed z-index and get them back to their original state, sth like that). Also beware of accessibility if cloning: is the element focusable and is the page still usable via keyboard only in the natural order of the elements or is there a need to be treated like a modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opted for the cloning option and have a solution in place that I'm luke-warm about, but seems to be functional. Here's the method I put together to create and position the clone:

```
var renderClonedEl = function($el, childrenToCopy) {
    var $clone = $($el[0].cloneNode(true)),
        offset = $el.offset(),
        styles = window.getComputedStyle($el[0], null).cssText,
        correction = {
            left: parseInt($el.css('margin-left')) + parseInt($el.css('border-left-width')),
            top: parseInt($el.css('margin-top')) + parseInt($el.css('border-top-width'))
        },
        $child, $cloneChild;

    childrenToCopy = childrenToCopy || []; // Use array of selector strings to copy addional styles between children elements
    $clone[0].style.cssText = styles;

    for (var i = 0; i < childrenToCopy.length; i++) {
        $child = $el.find(childrenToCopy[i]);
        $cloneChild = $clone.find(childrenToCopy[i]);

        _.each($cloneChild, function(item) {
            item.style.cssText = window.getComputedStyle($child[0], null).cssText;
        });
    };

    $clone.addClass('el-clone').appendTo('body').css({
        top: offset.top - correction.top,
        left: offset.left - correction.left
    });

    return $clone;
}
```

... additional helper styles for clone:

```
.el-clone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Call the method like so...

```
var $newClone = renderClonedEl($('.el-to-clone'), ['.header > .title', '.header .btn']);
```

I'm passing the original el over as a jQuery selection (because I have jQuery available to me). The `.offset()` method doesn't account for margin/padding/border-width so I'm adjusting for that.

childrenToCopy is an array of selection strings that I can pass to additionally copy computed styles from child elements over to the clone (when cloning a complex el with lots of children, some of them are losing styles).

I'm also returning the clone so the initiating code can properly destroy it once we're done.

I'm kinda sprinkling in a little jQuery and underscore amongst the vanilla stuff... I just happen to have both libraries available to me for this project.

Answer (score 1):

I would be quite afraid of cloning node that must be exposed, because of possibility of broken CSS selector or event handlers. Naturally, if you know your environment and if you are sure nothing could brake, it is probably good approach.

But in case the element of your interest happens to be plain rectangle, you can quite safely **obscure its surroundings** using overlay consisting of four smaller rectangles. I made a quick VanillaJS proof-of-concept (click around):

```js
function Obscurer() {
  this.cont = document.createElement('div')
  this.e1 = this.cont.appendChild(this.cont.cloneNode())
  this.e1.className = 'cover'
  this.e2 = this.cont.appendChild(this.e1.cloneNode())
  this.e3 = this.cont.appendChild(this.e1.cloneNode())
  this.e4 = this.cont.appendChild(this.e1.cloneNode())
}
Obscurer.prototype.obscureSurroundingsOf = function(el) {
  if (el.parentNode === this.cont) {
    document.body.removeChild(this.cont)
    return
  }
  var b = el.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.e1.style.width = b.left + b.width + 'px'
  this.e1.style.height = b.top + 'px'
  this.e2.style.left = this.e1.style.width
  this.e2.style.height = b.top + b.height + 'px'
  this.e3.style.top = this.e2.style.height
  this.e3.style.left = b.left + 'px'
  this.e4.style.top = b.top + 'px'
  this.e4.style.width = b.left + 'px'
  document.body.appendChild(this.cont)
}

var o = new Obscurer()

document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  o.obscureSurroundingsOf(ev.target)
})
```

```css
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>foo baz</p>
<p>baz <b>gazonk</b> <i>something</i></p>
<p>anything</p>
```

Comment: I appreciate the solution. I have several irregularly shaped areas that a cloning solution is better suited to, but I also have some rectangular areas that need to retain their functionality so I've ended up using both solutions with an optional param to switch between the two.